# What is the meaning of telling a story transparently?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of telling a story **transparently**, https://www.masterclass.com/classes/joyce-carol-oates-teaches-the-art-of-the-short-story ?

[image: telling a story transparently]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... way is that you're telling a story very transparently...

It means *to tell a story in a way that is easily understood*.

[Transparently](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/transparently) - easily understood, obvious.

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥

**Transparent (adj):** 
2. If a situation, system, or activity is transparent, it is easily understood or recognized. - [Collins English dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/transparent)

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥

Comment: I actually checked longman before I asked this question https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/transparent  but longman only said " if something is transparent, you can see through it" and that was why I don't understand in the context of telling a story. But now I understood. Thanks.

Comment: @Qiulang That is not my understanding. To tell something "transparently", to me means to tell it honestly, giving all the facts and, above all not hiding anything.

Comment: @WS2 But if you check the video she didn't seem to mean telling a story honestly.

Comment: @Qiulang You are right and I apologise for the short-sightedness of my comment. I have looked at the figurative uses in the OED. I think I was preoccupied with sense 2a, but perhaps what we are seeing here is 2b.

Answer (score 1):

The OED lists various figurative uses of the term ***transparent***. I believe what we are seeing here is an example of 2b.

> 2. figurative.
>
> **a. Frank, open, candid, ingenuous.** 1600   W. Shakespeare Midsummer >Night's Dream >ii. >ii. 110   Transparent Helena,
>   nature shewes arte, That through thy bosome, makes me see thy heart.
>       1635   Ld. Carew in Lismore Papers (1888) 2nd Ser. III. 217   They are very well beloued for their ciuill and transparent carriage
>   towards all sorts.
>
> 1878   T. Hardy Return of Native I. i. iv. 81   An ingenuous,
>   transparent life was disclosed.
>
> 1891   E. Peacock Narcissa Brendon II. 306   She was transparent as
>   the daylight.
>
> **b. Easily seen through, recognized, understood, or detected;
>   manifest, evident, obvious, clear.** Cf. apparent adj. 3.
>
> 1597   W. Shakespeare Romeo & Juliet i. ii. 93   Then turne teares to
>   fire, And these who often drownde could neuer die, Transparent
>   Heretiques be burnt for liers.    1638   W. Chillingworth Relig.
>   Protestants i. ii. §150. 111   Your Argument against us, is a
>   transparent fallacy.
>
> 1710   R. Steele Tatler No. 197. ⁋5   In Courts, they make transparent
>   Flatterers.
>
> 1867   E. A. Freeman Hist. Norman Conquest I. v. 347   A transparent
>   artifice..paralyses them.
>
> 1869   J. Martineau Ess. Philos. & Theol. 2nd Ser. 178   The fallacy
>   of the remark is transparent.
>
> 1879   J. McCarthy Hist. our Own Times II. xviii. 37   The transparent
>   sincerity of his purpose.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I can give both of you an accept check. On a different subject. I don't have a copy of ODE, but I read the book "the professor and the madman" and knew ODE uses the quotes from all kinds of books to show the word usage. And it is the first time I really saw that. Thanks! :D

Comment: @Qiulang The original book was called *The Surgeon of Crowthorne* by Simon Winchester. (It just so happens to be the village where I live). The film was called *The professor and the madman*. Perhaps they also published a book by that name which you read. Unfortunately the OED's on-line service requires a paid subscription. We are fortunate in the UK in that many of our municipal libraries hold subscriptions so we can access it from home by way of our library cards. But it is undoubtedly the leading authority on the English language as it is spoken worldwide, and its history.

Comment: @Qiulang The book version runs to about 27 volumes!

Comment: Yes, "the professor and the madman" mentioned that! So even I could access ODE I am not sure I want to read it :$ I usually use longman,  ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ to look up a word.  Longman dictionary is good enough for me!

Comment: @Qiulang It is OED. I think ODE is something else.

Comment: Oh right it is OED, sorry :$